# Tkinter Canvas получение координат курсора

Tags: python, tkinter

Как у `Tk.Canvas` спросить где находится мышка без `bind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root = tk.Tk()
...
x = root.winfo_pointerx()
y = root.winfo_pointery()
abs_coord_x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
abs_coord_y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943296/8206722)

Answer (score 2):

Немного улучшил ответ  [@Anton Komyshan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798269/255866) добавив обновление раз в секунду ,а не показ 1 раз при запуске программы

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cursor_position_print()

    def cursor_position_print(self):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.winfo_rootx()
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self.winfo_rooty()
        print("Курсор находится на позиции х={} y={}".format(x, y))
        self.after(1000, self.cursor_position_print)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Раз улучшили, то надо было добавить в его ответ с примечанием, что обновленный код.

Comment: @And не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос ( что вы хотите этим сказать) потому что мой ответ явно будет противоречить написание ответа автора.(если бы вопрос являлся бы общим то я бы мог добавить свой код в его ответ)